# mPdf - How do get word break?

Tags: mpdf

I have a justified text in mPDF within a column:

```
<columns column-count="2" vAlign="justify" column-gap="9" />
Lorem ipsum ....
```

Is it possible to get a word break, so you do not get such ugly lines:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: It's all described [in the documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/line-breaking.html).

Either split your words manually with Word break `U+200B` characters, or you can use mPDFs auto [hyphenation](https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/hyphenation.html) which has a dictionary for Deutsch already distributed with the package.

```
<?php

$mpdf = new mPDF();

$mpdf->SHYlang = 'de';
$mpdf->SHYleftmin = 3;

$mpdf->WriteHTML('auflauerte und hatte das Lebkuchenhäuschen bloß gebaut, um sie');

$mpdf->Output();
```

You can also use CSS property

```
hyphens: auto;
```

Entire hyphenation example can be found in the [mPDF examples repository](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf-examples/blob/master/example21_hyphenation.php).

Comment: Not sure why, but the `->SHYlang` has no effect -> i tried it out. The css works as expected and will solve my issue. It would be better to use an automatic dictorary, but its ok to add `&shy;` at places, where i want a linebreak.